# PhpStorm lost multiple features

Tags: intellij-idea, ide, phpstorm

My PhpStorm seems to have lost of a number of functions:

- I cannot <kbd>Ctrl+Click</kbd> on a variable to see its definition.
- The structure tab shows only the class name, not the methods.
- Find is not working. It just hangs.
- Double clicking inside a string does not select the string. Triple clicking does however still select the whole line.
- <kbd>CTRL+SHIFT+F10</kbd> does not launch a PHPUnit test. There are no test options in the top level menus, although My PHPUnit configuration is correctly in the settings

I have tried restarting PhpStorm, my OS, and I've also done `File > Invalidate Caches` and restart. None have helped. I've also upgraded to 2017.1.4 and that has made no difference either. I am running Ubuntu 16.10.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: 1) Start with disabling all not-bundled-by-default plugins 2) Check `idea.log` (Help | Show Log in...) for possible exceptions and other hints 3) You can always start from scratch (by deleting IDE-wide settings)

Comment: I had to delete my settings in the end. Please can you make this an answer can I can accept it?

Comment: Did you made a backup of them before deleting? Some of them can be safely re-used in new setup (e.g. keymap customisations, code style, external tools, live templates etc)

Answer (score 2):

If you did update or upgrade your PhpStorm by extracting new files from .tar.gz over the old location with replace, it could led to a libraries corruption and cause weird behavior.
PhpStorm files should always be extracted to an empty directory otherwise old generated files will interfere with new extracted files and cause such havoc.

Comment: I installed the new version into a brand new folder.

Answer (score 0):

Disable Power Save Mode if it's enabled.

Comment: It's not enabled.